# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: '404 (Not Found)'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, xamarin.android, google-authentication

I used this tutorial to create a Google Login for my App with Xamarin:
[Authenticate users through Google with Xamarin.Auth](http://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/)
I did it step by step but at the end, After I sign in to my google account I get this error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: '404 (Not Found)'

This part of code returns the error... When it tries to get the Email from API:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tokenType, accessToken);
var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email?alt=json");
var email = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Email>(json);
return email.Data.Email;
```

My config parameters:

- Google Client Id is correct => 437067938756-....apps.googleusercontent.com
- Google Scope is "email"
- GoogleRedirectUrl is blahbal:/oauth2redirect => blahblah is myAndroidManifest
- GoogleAuthorizeUrl is"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
- GoogleAccessTokenUrl is "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
- GoogleIsUsingNativeUI is true

Comment: ,404 means the server cannot find the requested page, so I suggest you can recheck the Url at first.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I think it's a wrong error... As you see in the code, the url is: https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email?alt=json

Comment: Was the error message the same on Android and iOS? Is the response different through a Keystore signed Android app?

Comment: @Saamer I only tried it on Android and used the Keystore that I created for my app!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error at some point. 
The issue was in incorrect certificate. 
Check if you are signing your app with Dev or Prod certificate.
Or you've updated/reinstalled xamarin and your dev cert has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But I didn't get what you exactly mean by Dev or Prod certificate. I used this tutorial to sign my app and get the Keystore: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows

Comment: Yes. And so make sure that when you are testing it that you are using Signed APKs to make it work